# What does it mean when something that resembles a program is "implemented in hardware"?

Tags: c, assembly

For example

```
/*
* This C-like algorithm is implemented in
* hardware as a single, atomic CAS instruction.
*/
int
CAS(int* ptr, int old, int new) 
{
    int tmp = *ptr;
    if (*ptr == old)
        *ptr = new;
    return tmp;
}
```

1. This clearly resembles a programing language so when they say it's implemented in hard ware do they mean this is algorithm the hardware uses and they're just expressing it using C syntax?
2. What does it mean "instruction"? Does it mean that it has it's own op code to instruct the CPU what to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Exactly. They are using C syntax to explain the result of the hardware operation. They are further stating that it acts as a single atomic operation, which means it can't be interrupted part way through by another thread.

2) I don't have the context of the statement, but that would be my assumption (that there is an atomic CAS instruction, with an opcode, that this is describing).

Comment: Also, it is worth noting that hardware-based functions are almost always faster than any software based counter part. A common practise in C is to wrap blocks of code with `#if ... - #else - #endif` statements so that on certain architectures a system specific block of assembly is run instead of the typical C code, such as hardware matrix multiplication or other operations that are greatly improved. Hardware barrel shifters are also another common example.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you answered your own question with your second point. If something is implemented in hardware that usually means that there is one instruction (even if that one instruction is actually a series of instructions wrapped into one) for that. This would mean that it should have it's own op code.

Comment: how can a series of instructions be wrapped into one?

Comment: @Celeritas - CISC CPUs have the notion of microcode - a single instruction can be broken into a stream of atomic internal operations (Atomic in terms of executing all-or-none and in terms of debug breakpoints, not memory semantics).